# Does the `map` call serve any purpose here?

Tags: rust, iterator

Code:

```
pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (&usize, &T)> + '_ {
    self.values.iter().map(|(key, value)| (key, value))
}
```

Quoted from [here](https://github.com/filecoin-project/bellperson/blob/master/src/lc.rs#L68), it seems following is enough:

```
pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (&usize, &T)> + '_ {
    self.values.iter()
}
```

Any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the former returns a type that implements `Iterator<Item = (&usize, &T)> + '_` while the latter returns a type that implements `Iterator<Item = &(usize, T)> + '_`.

Here a minimal example:

```rust
pub fn iter1(v: &[(usize, i32)]) -> impl Iterator<Item = (&usize, &i32)> + '_ {
    v.iter().map(|(key, value)| (key, value))
}

pub fn iter2(v: &[(usize, i32)]) -> impl Iterator<Item = (&usize, &i32)> + '_ {
    v.iter()
}
```

fails to compile with this error message:

```
error[E0271]: expected `std::slice::Iter<'_, (usize, i32)>` to be an iterator that yields `(&usize, &i32)`, but it yields `&(usize, i32)`
 --> src/lib.rs:5:37
  |
5 | pub fn iter2(v: &[(usize, i32)]) -> impl Iterator<Item = (&usize, &i32)> + '_ {
  |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `&(usize, i32)`, found tuple
6 |     v.iter()
  |     -------- return type was inferred to be `std::slice::Iter<'_, (usize, i32)>` here
  |
  = note: expected reference `&(usize, i32)`
                 found tuple `(&usize, &i32)`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0271`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f93265da4e88e0b8b3d2e18ee948de17)

The former works thanks to ergonomics build into Rust's pattern syntax called [binding modes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#binding-modes):

> When a reference value is matched by a non-reference pattern, it will be automatically treated as a ref or ref mut binding.

So it is basically syntactic sugar for  `v.iter().map(|&(ref key, ref value)| (key, value))`, which makes it clearer why the former works, but the latter doesn't.

Comment: I would elaborate on why this `map()` works.

Comment: I just edited it with a short explanation about patterns, is this what you had in mind @ChayimFriedman?